# Is a code-behind file the same as a view model?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, nativescript

I have a gap in my understanding of NativeScript which is stopping me moving forward with the 'getting started' tutorial documentation. I understand the basics principals, the modular JS structures and commonJS structures.

The tutorial documentation begins by introducing the MVVM principal which I fully understand. Then the tutorial begins to talk about the code-behind file. I understand the purpose of the code-behind file (to 'talk' with the view and provide two way binding between the view and the model), but things get a little nebulous (at least for me) when the tutorial moves on to the topics of the view model and model. It feels like the code-behind file *is* the view model, and so the NativeScript concept is:

-> A view  which displays my screen items (labels, fields etc.). Usually, but not necessarily an .XML file.

-> A code-behind file which sets up binding between view and model). This *is* the view model.

-> A model, for instance User model, or ShoppingCart model which might also perform API requests to get/put data

If that's the way it works then I can continue on with my learning but at the moment I'm not sure that the above is true. Can anyone shed light on this? Are my assumptions correct or have I missed something essential about the code-behind file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from the C# world here but I believe the 'code behind' terminology is derived from the C# world.

In C# WPF / Xamarin there is a .xaml file and a .cs that comprise the view, whereas in NativeScript there is a .xml file and .js code behind.

So the code behind is seen as ***part of*** the View and is separate from the ViewModel.

[NS documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-3#31-the-code-behind) seems to support this (based on the file names in the example) this but it is somewhat confusing

Comment: Thanks TheMachinist, but... would that not lead you to believe that there is a View file (login.xml)a Code-Behind (login.js), a ViewModel (login-viewmodel.js) AND a Model (users.js)?

Comment: That's what you have in C# - the codebehind and the xaml file are the view. In C# they are each a partial class - so together they are one class.

Comment: That's also why the xml and code behind have the same names. You use the code behind to add view logic.

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961263/is-it-alright-to-use-code-behind-of-view-to-be-view-model-in-mvvm?rq=1 which supports the above

Comment: "codebehind and the xaml file are the view", that seems to make sense. I'm marking this as correct thanks TheMachinist.

Comment: Follow up comment: Going back over the NativeScript documentation, specifically in the tutorial where they mention the MVVM structure in 'Adding a view model', they state:"The Observable is the view model in the MVVM design pattern. So, it's actually the Observable which is the VM. Which means it's View file, Code Behind file, View Model (via the Observable) and then Model such as User etc. The model looks after creating a class/model for your data object and has methods/functions to for example reach out to API services for CRUD operations. Makes sense now.